# Problems adding rows to a UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am trying to add cells to a UITableView without reloading the table. I have been able to add an object, but if I delete an object and then try to add another one, it doesn't work and I get the error message listed bellow. Here is the code I am using to add a row and to delete a row:

Add a row:

```
-(void)addSelected:(UIButton *)sender {

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:self.periodArray.count inSection:0];

    [self.classTableView beginUpdates];
    NSLog(@"Previous Period count: %lu", (unsigned long)self.periodArray.count-1);
    [self.periodArray addObject:@"Period 8"];
    NSArray *newResults = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath, nil];
    [self.classTableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:newResults withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
    [self.classTableView endUpdates];
    self.classTableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44*[self.periodArray count]+63);
}
```

To delete:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    [self.classTableView beginUpdates];
    [self.periodArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self.classTableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths: @[ indexPath ] withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    NSLog(@"Period count after delete: %lu", (unsigned long)self.periodArray.count);
    [self.classTableView endUpdates];
}
```

Error Message:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 6 beyond bounds [0 .. 5]'
```

Comment: In which line is the exception reported?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete your row from the underlying array ***after*** you delete it from the table.

That is:

```
[self.classTableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths: @[ indexPath ] withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
[self.periodArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

And you should be good to go.

Comment: I still get the same error message even with this switch

Comment: No, I fixed it, it was a problem with something else